# Help me to prove that $|BA|\leq|B||A|$ holds

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the norm $|A|= \sqrt{tr(A^*A)}$, where $tr$ is the trace of a linear operator, help to prove that $|BA| \leq |B||A|$ holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cauchy-Schwarz gives:
$$
\begin{split}
|BA|^2&=\mathrm{trace}((BA)^*(AB))=\sum_{i,j}|(BA)_{ij}|^2=\sum_{ij}\left|\sum_k b_{ik}a_{kj}\right|^2
\leq\sum_{ij}\left(\sum_k|b_{ik}|^2\sum_k|a_{kj}|^2\right)
\\&=
\sum_{i,k}|b_{ik}|^2\sum_{j,k}|a_{jk}|^2=|B|^2|A|^2.
\end{split}
$$

Answer (score 1):

We have $\|A\|_F^2 = \sum_k \|A e_k \|_2^2 = \sum_k \|e_k^TA \|_2^2$, and
 $\|Ax\|_2^2 = \sum_k |e_k^T A x|^2 \le \sum_k \|e_k^TA \|_2^2 \|x\|_2^2 = \|A\|_F^2 \|x\|_2^2$.

Combining, we get $\|BA\|_F^2 = \sum_k \|BA e_k\|_2^2 \le \|B\|_F^2 \sum_k \|A e_k \|_2^2 = \|B\|_F^2\|A\|_F^2  $.